# Where can I find documentation for RDLC xml?

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

I'm trying to find documentation on RDLC.

Specifically I'm looking for the different `Actions` in a `TextBox` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the RDL specifications for the various SQL Server versions here:

- [SQL Server RDL Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

On page 41, you get a list of possible actions:

> Action The Action element defines a
>   **hyperlink, bookmark link or
>   drillthrough** action associated with a
>   ReportItem.

According to [Got Reportviewer?](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/), RDLC and RDL share the same format:

> Q8: What is the difference between RDL
>   and RDLC formats?
>
> A: RDL files are created by the SQL
>   Server 2008 version of Report
>   Designer. RDLC files are created by
>   the Visual Studio 2008 version of
>   Report Designer.
>
> **RDL and RDLC formats have the same XML
>   schema.** However, in RDLC files, some
>   values (such as query text) are
>   allowed to be empty, which means that
>   they are not immediately ready to be
>   published to a Report Server. The
>   missing values can be entered by
>   opening the RDLC file using the SQL
>   Server 2008 version of Report
>   Designer. (You have to rename .rdlc to
>   .rdl first.)